Apigateway spring boot forward routing problem?
i have a problem in the apigatway routing i get 404
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: client-microservice
          uri: ${client-microservice_Route_URI:http://localhost:9092} 
          predicates:
            - Path=/client-microservice/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

so http://localhost:9092/api/clients works fine but http://localhost:8080/client-microservice/api/clients does not and the microservices are both in eurika server and fine
the main issue i think is in
 filters:
            - StripPrefix=1

but i dont know

What is the value of client-microservice_Route_URI?
